# How to return an array in C# without creating array inside the method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return-type

I have to return an array after doing a little calculation. But I dont know how to do it without creating an array inside the method.

```
int[] arr = numbers(number1, number2); // this is in the main function
```

This is the method I have created

```
static int[] numbers(int number1, int number2)
{
     for(int i=number1; i<=number2; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            return [i++]=i;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This is what I have done so far, But it has compile time error. 
All I want to do is return if the values in i is odd to array in main method.

Please note that I don't want to create another array in the numbers method.

Original question is about finding odd numbers within a given range. Number1 and number2 are the range limits. No change in the method declaration. And the content can be created as I want. And finally it should return as in the method's return type. What ever the returning thing will be captured by a integer array. Thats all and finally print the array

Comment: Who's going to create the array then? What are you *really* trying to do? Why not create the array inside the method? Or create an array *field* and return a reference to it, with the associated bugs and risk of returning stale, dirty or suddenly changed data?

Comment: If you tell us why you want to do such thing, may be there is another solution?

Comment: But ... why? Right now your question reads like this: *"How do I create an array without creating an array?"*. Do you want to **fill** an array that was created in another method? Do you need something more flexible than a array because you don't know how many elements it's going to have?

Comment: Why you are not using a reference to use in the new function ?

Comment: You could return an `IEnumerable<int>` with `yield return` instead and call `ToArray` outside of the method, but the question remains: Why? (Also, whats `l` and `r`?)

Comment: Of course it will have compile time error, first thing is that you have to return `int[]` but returning `0`. Also what is this -> `[i++]=i;`?

Comment: In order to *return* an instance of a class (in your case an array), you have to *create* one. Maybe you allready have one that you want to provide into the method?

Comment: @All this is a question found on the internet. That's why I'm having this problem. I know it's easy if  I could create array and assign to it. But that is not the expected answer

Comment: Could you be more specific where you found that and what the answer is if you have it allready?

Comment: You get compile time errors because `l` and `r` are nowhere and `return [i++]=i` is not valid C#

Comment: @Sem Im just trying to figure out a way. That's is the place where I need help

Comment: @joe you could take by reference an array and update it, but if this is "a question found on the internet" why are you asking it here, what do you actually need to achieve

Comment: I dont have the answer.

Comment: @Joe *"A question found on the internet"*, so what's the question **exactly**? Where did you find it? What's the context?

Comment: This sounds like a homework issue and someone that doesn't what he has to do..

Comment: @Joe what is the *actual* question then? What you posted isn't enough to give an answer. And I bet whoever wrote the question wouldn't have thought of the best answers either, or what the *problems* may be with the chosen answer

Comment: @Joe you are trying to figure out the way, but you are not telling us actual problem, just explain what you have and what you want as a result and show us what you have tried to achieve that, then we will help you.

Comment: [Spans](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md) can do this, and do it in a safe way as well. I doubt whoever wrote this question knows about spans though. Probably an unsafe buffer allocation and casting, that no-one would actually use ?

Comment: @Joe can you share the question you found on the internet with us?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk put the iterator in a local function, return `.ToArray()` and wait for the examiner's reactions :P

Comment: Another possibility: use `Enumerable.Range(number1,number2-number1).Where(it=>it%2==1).ToArray()`. `ToArray()` *does* create an array but at least there's no `new int[]` call. Make it an expression bodied method too: `static int[] numbers(int number1, int number2) => Enumerable.Range(number1,number2-number1).Where(it=>it%2==1).ToArray();`

Comment: You want to return a sub-list of your input obviously, which *is* a completely new list (or in your case an array). In order to return all odd numbers you *have* to create some kind of a collection that *contains* those numbers, be it a list, an array or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<int> Number(int number1, int number2){
    for(int i=number1; i<=number2; i++) {
        if(i%2==1) {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
static int[] Number(int number1, int number2){
    var x = new int[number2];
    int y = 0;
    for(int i=number1; i<=number2; i++) {
        if(i%2==1) {
            x[y] = i;
            y++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

This is what you are looking for without creating an array

Call it like:

```
var something = Number(1,5).ToArray();
```

Comment: Jordy Really appreciate the answer. But I'm allowed to change only the body of the method Numbers

Comment: @Joe I think you are in some coding site and passing test or something.

Comment: @Joe SO isn't a quizz-answering service. You haven't even posted the actual question yet. As for the quizz, you realize you've already failed it?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk Just to be evil, make the iterator a local function and call `ToArray()` when returning. Think the quiz accepts C# 7 answers?

Comment: This it to improve myself. Yeah the question is on the internet. But this is something I dont know. I've searched a lot. But didn't find anything like this. That'a why asked it here

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ ... yeah, you're right of course. Sometimes it's a bit hard to stay nice when this is the 10th question of this quality in a row.

Comment: I have included all the requirements. If you want I can add more description

Comment: @Joe no you didn't ask. You only posted part of the question. There are so **many** possible answers it's infuriating. And this answer works if you make it a local function inside the `Numbers` function. Extreme, yes, but covers what you asked until now

Comment: @Joe that's why we usually require a [mcve].

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Believe me, I understand you, I'm just keeping me calm when I comment, there is completely opposite going on in my mind sometimes :)

Comment: @Jordy I dont think its gonna work

Comment: @joe Why not? If you need something different you need to change your question

Comment: Tried to change the code. It didnt work Jordy

Comment: I updated the answer. The second party’s does what you need. But you need to make sure number1 is smaller than number2

Comment: Actually they give the inputs. And use this method to get the output. So I believe they consider about this issue

Comment: @Joe The second part is exactly what you looking for. You don't change the signature of the method but only the body. It will return an array of `odd` numbers between `number1` and `number2`. They can call it like `numbers(3,5)` and it will return `[3,5]` or `numbers(0,10)` and it will return `[1,3,5,7,9]` if they call it with `number(3,1)` it will not return any numbers but an empty array

Comment: @Jordy, you code seems to be working but it creates additional zero's when the range is getting bigger. How can I avoid it?

Comment: @Joe If you change `x = new int[number2]` to `x=new List<int>()` and add the number to x by using `x.Add(i)` inside your if and at the end where it says `return x` you return `return x.ToArray()` And please mark the answer as correct if it works for you!

Comment: Yes it did. thanks a lot Jordy. I will accept the answer.